# Cauchy Integral Theorem for punctured domains comprehension (seems too powerful)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

We are supposed to calculate a few integrals where the integrand is a quotient of holomorphic functions. Wikipedia says (and there is a proof on this site) that the quotient $(f/g)$ is holomorphic wherever $g\ne 0$.

We also have the following lemma from class:

> Let $G$ be a simply connected domain, $c \in G$, and let $f \in C(G)$ be holomorphic on $G \setminus \{c\}$. Then for all closed piecewise $C^1$-paths $\gamma$ in $G$ $$\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 0$$

This seems way too strong a formula (as far as I understand it). For instance the integrals

1. $$\int_{\partial D} \frac{\cosh(z)}{4z^3-z}dz$$
2. $$\int_{\partial D} \frac{\cos(\pi z)}{(z-2)^3}dz$$

would evaluate to zero, as long as the closed disks $D$ contain **at most** one of the roots of the denominator function:

1. $\{-0.5,0,0.5\}$
2. $\{2\}$

respectively. This root would then be our $c$, $D$ our connected domain $G$, and f would be holomorphic on $G\setminus\{c\}$.

I have a strong feeling this is wrong, as it seems too good to be true. But many properties of holomorphic functions seem too good to be true, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: That "lemma" is false: consider $f(z)=1/(z-c)$ and $\gamma$ a small circle with centre $c$. You need to read up on Cauchy's Integral  Formula.

Comment: You seem to have missed that $f$ is assumed to be continuous on $G$. When you have a pole, that condition is violated.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The lemma has $f \in C(G)$ among the hypotheses.

Comment: If the hypotheses are satisfied, doesn't $f$ have a removable singularity at $c$?  So this is really just the Cauchy integral theorem, thinly disguised?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, but the lemma (or at least the version of it where the path $\gamma$ is the boundary of a triangle contained in $G$) is often used to build the theory and Riemann's removable singularity theorem is proved using this result. A priori, one doesn't know that "a continuous function that is holomorphic except maybe at finitely many points" is no more general than "a holomorphic function".

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks.  I guess I just remember the result and not the derivation.  I'll have to look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. In order to apply that theorem in order to compute $\displaystyle\int_{\partial D}\frac{\cosh(z)}{4z^3-z}\,\mathrm dz$, the disk $D$ must contain **none** of the roots of $4z^3-z$. Otherwise, $\dfrac{\cosh(z)}{4z^3-z}\notin C(D)$, since, for each $z_0\in\left\{-\frac12,0,\frac12\right\}$, the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{\cosh(z)}{4z^3-z}$ doesn't exist.